# Get average color of an image

Tags: delphi

I am trying to get the average color of an image. I tried various methods and now I use the following code, but I could not get the correct result.

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code?

```
  //load bitmap to curimg
  img1.Picture.Bitmap := curimg ; //testing the previous line

  //My image is always greater than 25x25 but I only need a 25x25 box

  for I := 0  to 25 do
  begin
    for y := 0  to 25 do
    begin
      r := r + GetRValue(curimg.Canvas.Pixels[y, I]);
      g := g + GetGValue(curimg.Canvas.Pixels[y, I]);
      b := b + GetBValue(curimg.Canvas.Pixels[y, I]);
    end;
  end;
  r := r div (25 * 25);
  g := g div (25 * 25);
  b := b div (25 * 25);
  rgbk := RGB(r, g, b);
  Result = rgbk;
end;
```

`img1` and `image1` of type `TImageBox` are on my form.

Comment: i am getting a color which seems to be not the average color

Comment: how many bits per pixel?

Comment: By the way, I see at the moment you're working with a 25x25 subset, but something to be aware of: if you're accumulating each pixel in your `r`, `g` and `b` variables which are `integer`s, beware of overflow.  A signed 32-bit integer's maximum value is 2147483647, which sounds a lot, but if every pixel was 255 then you'd hit it with an image 2902x2902 pixels big - that's actually not unreasonably large.

Comment: If anyone (like me) use this snippet to calculate image average be aware to swap y and I in the GetXValue functions. If you have a picture that is not square (unlike this question) then the calculation probably gets wrong result. Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local variables `r,g,b: integer` should be initialized to zero first.

Comment: Didn't the compiler warn you that the variables weren't initialized, Vibeeshan?

Answer (score 3):

One thing which seems wrong with this is that in comments you say that you have 25*25 image, but you loop over 26*26 pixels, so the loops should be:

```
for I := 0  to 24 do
  begin
    for y := 0  to 24 do
```

Comment: thanks ; but more than this  i am getting a color which seems to be not the average color